# Building sensitivity heat maps in R

Tags: r, heatmap

I’m trying to build a sensitivity heat map in R but I have a problem to define values for the x- and y-axes.

For example, I would like to build the heat map showing the variable `L` along variables `nA` on the x-axis and `nB` on the y-axis. But, I don't know how to define the x- and y- axes for `nA` and `nB` given that these variables depend on population sizes `A` and `B` that are also used to define the variables `nAH` and `nBH`. Using my code, I obtain white lines in the heat map. Here is my code:

```
## Define input parameters
dat <- expand.grid(V = 425,
                       A = round(seq(0, 4000, length.out = 100)),
                       B = round(seq(0, 3160, length.out = 100)),
                       C = 25,
                       fVA = 0.09,
                       fVB = 0.04,
                       gAV = 0.92,
                       gBV = 0.12, 
                       gVA = 0.83, 
                       gVB = 0.83, 
                       oV = 3.274796e-08,
                       pV = 425,
                       qV = 195903.7,
                       kVp = 425,
                       kVm = 42,
                       dA = 0.01,
                       dB = 0.001,
                       kA = 4000,
                       kB = 3160,
                       rA = 0.01,
                       rB = 0.019)

## Add new parameters
dat$nVH <- dat[,c("V")]/(dat[,c("A")] + dat[,c("B")] + dat[,c("C")])
dat$nAH <- dat[,c("A")]/(dat[,c("A")] + dat[,c("B")] + dat[,c("C")])
dat$nBH <- dat[,c("B")]/(dat[,c("A")] + dat[,c("B")] + dat[,c("C")])
dat$nA <- dat[,c("A")]/dat[,c("kA")]
dat$nB <- dat[,c("B")]/dat[,c("kB")]

## Define the equation for L: 
dat$L <- sqrt( (((dat$fVA)^2)*dat$gAV*dat$gVA*dat$nVH*dat$nAH)/((dat$oV*(dat$pV*dat$V + dat$kVp*dat$kVm + dat$qV))*(dat$dA + dat$rA*dat$nA)) +
                    (((dat$fVB)^2)*dat$gBV*dat$gVB*dat$nVH*dat$nBH)/((dat$oV*(dat$pV*dat$V + dat$kVp*dat$kVm + dat$qV))*(dat$dB + dat$rB*dat$nB)))
summary(dat)

## Build the sensitivity heat map
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(nA, nB, z = L)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = L)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = terrain.colors(10), name = "L") + 
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 16),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 16),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.title = element_text(size = 16))
```

Here is the resulting heat map

[image]

The expected result will be a heat map without white lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this by mapping `color` to `L` as well, and then matching the `color` gradient scale to the `fill` gradient:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(nA, nB, fill = L, color = L)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = terrain.colors(10), name = "L") + 
  scale_color_gradientn(colours = terrain.colors(10), name = "L") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 16),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 16),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.title = element_text(size = 16))
```

[image]